# expect uqualified-id before ";" token

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error and I am not sure why.  I get the error posted in the question title.  If I take the semicolon out of the class line I get expected semicolon after class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#ifndef die_h
#define die_h


using namespace std;


class Dice;
{
private:
int sides;
int value;

public:
Dice(int=6);
void cast();
int getSides();
int getvalue();


return 0;

}

#endif
```

Comment: Take the semi-colon from `Dice` and give it to the closing `}`.

Comment: The "expected semicolon after class" is after the *entire* class definition... not after `class Dice`.

Comment: What is this funny looking "return 0;". What exactly is returning here?

Comment: ok, thanks, that resolved that, now I get expected unqualified id before return, any thoughts?

Comment: Do not return 0 from a class declaration. Add a semicolon after the last '}'. Lastly, check a tutorial on the basis of C++ classes.

Comment: Sweet, took out the return and I'm home free, thanks!